# jquery each don't work

Tags: jquery, dom

Here is my query code

```
function translateTo(lang) {
    if (TRAINER_MULTILANG > 0) {
        $.getScript("js/lang/trainer.lang."+lang+".js")
            .done(function(script,textStatus) {
                pushLang(I18N);
                TRAINER_CURRENT_LANG = lang;
            })
            .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
                console.log("[i18n] Failed to load langfile. Loading default () instead...");
                $.getScript("js/lang/trainer.lang."+TRAINER_DEFAULT_LANG+".js")
                    .done(function(script,textStatus) {
                        pushLang(I18N);
                        TRAINER_CURRENT_LANG = TRAINER_DEFAULT_LANG;
                    });
            });
    } else {
        $.getScript("js/lang/trainer.lang."+TRAINER_DEFAULT_LANG+".js")
            .done(function(script,textStatus) {
                pushLang(I18N);
            });
    }
}
function pushLang(data) {
    $('[data-i18n="true"]').each(function (e) {
        $(this).html(data[$(this).html()]);
    });
}
```

My html looks like:

```
<span data-i18n="true">LANT_LANG_CONSTANT1</span>
<span data-i18n="true">LANT_LANG_CONSTANT2</span>
```

And js/lang/trainer.lang... files looks like:

```
var I18N = {
    LANT_LANG_CONSTANT1:  'etc'
}
```

The problem is that my function translateTo works only once, right after including js file with this functions, before . And text changes only if i reupdate content. Is it possible to make something?

Comment: it's definitely possible to make something :D :D ... and how many times you're calling `translateTo()`? and where do you call it?

Comment: heh) right after including js file with this functions, before </body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that your lang constants html strings get replaced with the translated text.
You could get around that problem if you save the constant inside a data attribute. So:

```
<span data-i18n="true" data-constant="LANT_LANG_CONSTANT1"></span>
<span data-i18n="true" data-constant="LANT_LANG_CONSTANT2"></span>
```

then in your pushLang:

```
function pushLang(data) {
    $('[data-i18n="true"]').each(function (e) {
        $(this).html(data[$(this).data('constant')]);
    });
}
```

Edit:

If you don't want to change all your html constants, you could save the constant into the data object when you first call pushLang:

```
function pushLang(data) {
    $('[data-i18n="true"]').each(function (e) {
        if(!$(this).data('constant')){
             $(this).data('constant', $(this).html());
        }

        $(this).html(data[$(this).data('constant')]);
    });
}
```